How can i store a list of class in Hive?
i have a itemlist which i fetched from api with a model class.now i want to save the list in hive with some other property like customer name customer address and obviously itemsList.
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import '../item_model.dart';
import 'hive_model.dart';
part 'saved_hive_model.g.dart';
@HiveType(typeId: 15)
class SavedDatInHive {
@HiveField(10)
final String totalPrice;
@HiveField(11)
final List<ItemList> list;
@HiveField(12)
final String CustomerName;
SavedDatInHive(this.list, this.CustomerName, {required this.totalPrice});}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First of all, let me offer you an easier method that may be useful to you;

1- Create classes

Create your classes this way. I assume the 'ItemList' class already exists.
final class SavedDatInHive {
  final String totalPrice;
  final List<ItemList> list;
  final String customerName;

  SavedDatInHive({required this.totalPrice, required this.list, required this.customerName});

  // toJson method
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'totalPrice': totalPrice,
      'list': list.map((item) => item.toJson()).toList(),
      'customerName': customerName,
    };
  }

  // fromJson method
  factory SavedDatInHive.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SavedDatInHive(
      totalPrice: json['totalPrice'],
      list: (json['list'] as List).map((item) => ItemList.fromJson(item)).toList(),
      customerName: json['customerName'],
    );
  }
}

final class ItemList {
  // Your normal class fields
  final String itemName;
  final int quantity;

  ItemList({required this.itemName, required this.quantity});

  // toJson method
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'itemName': itemName,
      'quantity': quantity,
    };
  }

  // fromJson method
  factory ItemList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ItemList(
      itemName: json['itemName'],
      quantity: json['quantity'],
    );
  }
}

Next, remember that Hive can only store values ​​like int, string, bool, etc. So if you want to save different data types or classes in Hive, you will need TypeAdapters. And there must be TypeAdapters for each different class within the class that will work with Hive.
If the parameters you define in the class do not have a TypeAdapter, you must create one for each of them.
///
///Example : 


///  You must be create an TypeAdapter for this one 
final class SavedDatInHive {
  final String totalPrice;
  

  ///  Also, You must be create an TypeAdapter for this one 
  final List<ItemList> list;

  /// 
  ///

  final String customerName;

  SavedDatInHive({required this.totalPrice, required this.list, required this.customerName});
}


2- Create TypeAdapters for each class

final class SavedDatInHiveAdapter extends TypeAdapter<SavedDatInHive> {
  @override
  SavedDatInHive read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final asd = reader.read();
    final jsonConverted = jsonEncode(asd);
    return SavedDatInHive.fromJson(json.decode(jsonConverted) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }

  @override
  int get typeId => 1; // Same like HiveType(1)

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, SavedDatInHive obj) {
    writer.write(obj.toJson());
  }
}


final class ItemListHiveAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ItemList> {
  @override
  ItemList read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final asd = reader.read();
    final jsonConverted = jsonEncode(asd);
    return ItemList.fromJson(json.decode(jsonConverted) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }

  @override
  int get typeId => 2; // Same like HiveType(1)

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, ItemList obj) {
    writer.write(obj.toJson());
  }
}


3- Finally, define Adapters in the section where the Hive service launcher is located.

 final appDocumentDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await Hive.initFlutter(appDocumentDir.path);

 Hive
      ..registerAdapter(SavedDatInHiveAdapter())
      ..registerAdapter(ItemListHiveAdapter());
/// Example Usage
 Hive.box<SavedDatInHive>("YourBoxKeyName")..add(SavedDatInHive(totalPrice: "1923", list: [], customerName: "Rasit"));

That's all, I hope you found it useful.
